How do I vertex snap to loose geometry?
It used to be easy to snap to loose vertices, but ever since a few versions of blender ago, it is essentially impossible:

This behavior is consistent in both solid and wire frame mode, with little if any difference in what kinds of verts can be snapped to.
Very occasionally, you can still snap to loose geometry. This usually involves being in wireframe, ortho view, and zooming in as far as it is possible to. You get a circle X icon over the targeted vertex:

How do I change the behavior back to how it was in older versions of Blender?

The issue is probably not with loose geometry per-se, most likely the fact that is overlapping/very close to other geometry. Precision issues will make it appear occluded in solid mode from certain points of view, or far away

Are you talking about vertex which is part of a mesh but not connected to it, or one on a subdivided edge as it looks in your image? - I've found that snapping seems to be more reliable if you have it turned off on the toolbar, hover over the vertex you want to snap to, hit G then the Ctrl key and Enter.

Try with the Snap With Active option enabled, see screenshot below:

Now with the active vertex selected (white vertex in gif below) hit the G key, move the mouse towards the vertex you want to snap to and then hit the Ctrl key to activate the snapping mode.
Example with target vertex in edit mode:

and target vertex in Object mode:

Edit:
Checking with Blender 4.1 is as you indicated, not possible to snap to the loose vertices aligned to an edge:

But perfectly possible with Blender 3.6 :


I have literally the exact same settings and cannot replicate that behavior. To clarify, the problem vertex for me is NOT part of an edge. it is a free-floating vertex that happens to sit on another edge. Is the vertex in the middle of that edge part of the edge, or just sitting on top of it?

The vertex in the middle of the edge was part of the edge. I just tried with loose vertices aligned to an edge and the result is as you indicated in your question. So unfortunately other than temporarily hiding the edge I don't have a solution. I have edited my answer by adding examples in Blender 4.1 and Blender 3.6.
